# PHP MySQL better strategy for returning query results

Tags: php, web

I have just dived into the world of web development and started with basics of PHP and MySQL. My assignment included a question where we had to send a request to the server (I was using XAMPP) which would run a MySQL query with the database and return the results. While I did the question and `echo`'ed the results of a `select` query from the PHP on the client page when there was just one user (that is me), I wondered whether it was the right way to do it when there are multiple users using the application.

Is the server here doing extra processing viz the `echo` statements? Would returning the query results (an object in this case) to the client and let it render the HTML using AJAX, be a better option? If yes, then why? If no, then what could be a better way to implement this?

Apologies if it's too basic.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','employee','3307');
$text = $_GET['userInput'];
$sql = "";
switch($_GET['emp'])
{
case "EID": 
            $sql .= "Select * from employee where 'Employee ID' = '$text';";
            break;

case "ENAME": 
            $sql .= "Select * from employee where Name = '$text';";
            break;

case "DNO": 
            $sql .= "Select * from employee where 'Department No.' = '$text';";
            break;

case "LOC": 
            $sql .= "Select * from employee where 'Location' = '$text';";
            break;
}

$result_set = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$str = "";
if(mysqli_num_rows($result_set)>0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set))
    {
        echo ($row['Employee ID'].$row['Name'].$row['Department No.'].$row['Salary'].$row['Location']."<br>");
        //$rows[] = $r;
    }
}
?>
```

Pardon the non standard code.

Comment: can you show us your code? it makes it easy to resolve :)

Comment: @RyanEarnshaw edited the question

Comment: This code works as is? You are open to SQL injections and are using the wrong encapsulation for columns, backticks, not quotes. Then again `$sql` is never used

Comment: @chris85 i was using a simple `select` query to check whether it works or not and it did work. Just edited and put `$sql` there. and that security is probably the first thing i'm gonna study after resolving this.

Comment: You should deal with the default case in your switch. What if &emp=fluffy bunnies or &emp ='' etc... Also take note of your field names. You refer to Department No, then refer to it as DepartmentNo. Which is it to be?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw it was indeed `Department No.` Inconsistencies came in when i edited the code here. Could you explain a little about &emp thing ?

Comment: I was assuming you are passing emp via the URL as you are using GET. So I assumed it was the 2nd entry if that were the case... it has a & and not a ? in the query string.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw emp is the first argument of the query string.

Comment: ok so what if emp = IamHackingYou. How are you dealing with that?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw i have not yet dived into the security issues however I know that validating the user input and escaping the characters is an important consideration with this code but as i mentioned in the question - pardon the non standard code..and thanks for your concern

Comment: Neither validation or escaping is essential. You should be using prepared statements

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have just bookmarked your profile for understanding the security issues. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "separate process" to echo the results, and it's perfectly OK to use your current way to output from PHP.

Comment: Your code could be improved in many other ways though, notably using prepared statements. But for such a review you should post a question on codereview.stackexchange.com